# Player getting stuck on the map

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made my first game in unity,it is running smoothly.

It has a player and aliens and a map as usual.

sometimes the player gets stuck and does not move forward,
even though the animation of player moving forward runs and his legs keeps moving but still it doesn't move

I have to move in other directions and then it can pass through that point where it got stuck

It happens randomly and not on any fixed spot.

and I am not able to figure out why this is happening

I tried to make the map again but still its there

Any suggestions would be a great help.

ublic class Player : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float speed = 10f;
public Vector2 maxVelocity = new Vector2(3, 5);
public bool standing;
public float jetSpeed = 15f;
public float airSpeedMultiplier = .3f;
public AudioClip leftFootSound;
public AudioClip rightFootSound;
public AudioClip thudSound;
public AudioClip rocketSound;
public Vector3 PlayerDirection = new Vector3(1,1,1);
public int ArtifactCount = 0;

private Animator animator;
private PlayerController controller;

void Start(){
    controller = GetComponent<PlayerController> ();
    animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}



void PlayLeftFootSound(){
    if (leftFootSound)
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (leftFootSound, transform.position);
}

void PlayRightFootSound(){
    if (rightFootSound)
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (rightFootSound, transform.position);
}

void PlayRocketSound(){
    if (!rocketSound || GameObject.Find ("RocketSound"))
        return;

    GameObject go = new GameObject ("RocketSound");
    AudioSource aSrc = go.AddComponent<AudioSource> ();
    aSrc.clip = rocketSound;
    aSrc.volume = 0.7f;
    aSrc.Play ();

    Destroy (go, rocketSound.length);

}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D target){
    if (!standing) {
        var absVelX = Mathf.Abs(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x);
        var absVelY = Mathf.Abs(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);

        if(absVelX <= .1f || absVelY <= .1f){
            if(thudSound)
                AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(thudSound, transform.position);
        }
    }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    var forceX = 0f;
    var forceY = 0f;

    var absVelX = Mathf.Abs (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x);
    var absVelY = Mathf.Abs (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);

    if (absVelY < .2f) {
        standing = true;
    } else {
        standing = false;
    }

    if (controller.moving.x != 0) {
        if (absVelX < maxVelocity.x) {

            forceX = standing ? speed * controller.moving.x : (speed * controller.moving.x * airSpeedMultiplier);

            PlayerDirection = transform.localScale = new Vector3 (forceX > 0 ? 1 : -1, 1, 1);

        }
        animator.SetInteger ("AnimState", 1);
    } else {
        animator.SetInteger ("AnimState", 0);
    }

    if (controller.moving.y > 0) {
        PlayRocketSound();
                    if (absVelY < maxVelocity.y)
                            forceY = jetSpeed * controller.moving.y;

                    animator.SetInteger ("AnimState", 2);
            } else if (absVelY > 0) {
        animator.SetInteger("AnimState", 3);
            }

    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce (new Vector2 (forceX, forceY));
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Suggestion: use a debugger to see what's going on when your program working not as expected. Noone here except you can reproduce this since it happens "sometimes". Also it is not possible to make any assumptions without seeing your application code.

Comment: This should probably be posted on the specific Unity/Games stackexchange

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone can help you since we know nothing about your code. *Describing* the code is unnecessary.

Comment: Which part of the code should i post? the map doesn't have any code, will paste the player code

Comment: Physics code should be placed in FixedUpdate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that the point you are going is not outside your map.

I think that when you are adding forces to the rigidbody you can add "too much" forces and that rigidbody collides with something and after that it get stacked.

Edit:

Check the OnCollisionEnter, OnCollisionStay and Exit also the triggers.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html

Comment: No the player stays in the map only, have made two layers, so it can not go out of the boundaries and the stacking thing was also happening but in this case there is no object with the player only the maps design and rest of the place is empty so it can not collide with anything

Comment: If the collider of the player is inside the wall collider then you get that kind of problems.

You can try to change the AddForce by moving it with the transform.position